# privilege dropping possible in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, security, privileges

I wonder if it would be possible to drop privileges in Javascript?

```
function takeAwaySetTimeout()
{
  var oldSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
  window.setTimeout = function()
  {
    console.log("not working anymore!");
  };
}


setTimeout("console.log('this works');",0);  // "this works!"
takeAwaySetTimeout();
setTimeout("console.log('this works');",0);  // "not working anymore!"
```

unfortunatelly it seesm to me complicated as a simple `delete window.setTimeout` will bring back the priviledge! So for me this seems indicative to the fact that unfortunatelly Javascript would not provide for taken away privileges.

I am aware that the term **privilege** is somewhat borrowed.
It is the background to the question that I would conceive any possiblity to workingly remove a `[Native Code] function` (= that the method `.toSource()` indicates its an function provided by the javascript engine) from being accessible in some part as a way to secure the code subjected to this limitation (the privileges are dropped) from being less of a safety concern.

### clarification

I **welcome** your request for more clarity, and hope your will respond to it responsibly and de-hold "free" the question!
Please also consider that **having received indeed already two helpful answers** shows that, there are people who were able to understand the question. Yet sure, if possible (something simply need background....) I also strive for broadening the understanding.

"It's a bit unclear how restricting access to native functions would give more security. Is 
this server-side or client-side JavaScript?"

1) it does not very much matter if client or server-side. Maybe a tiny little bit more important seems of course server-side. Because there is likely likely more functionality (i.e. writing to files, access files.....), more then maybe the more limited Javascript inside of Browser would be able to do (but consider new API's power ...and risks!)

2) maybe the choice for `window.setTimeout()` [Native function] is not perfect (for clarity), as maybe no direct security relationship is obvious. It has been used because it is well known and it is placeholder. see (3)

3) my reasoning is that each functionality that is provided to Javascript code is ambivalent. On the **pro** side, it enriches "what it can do?" positively and well-meaning code will use it responsible. Yet on the **con** side a functionality can mean access to things which when abused can cause security related stuff. An example would be that an external Javacript would do a XHR and post information to the server, potentially data that has private data (i.e. customers health state). If then for example it was possible to take away the XHR object better `window.XMLHttpRequest` the chances for such an abuse would be limited. Plainly "you cannot shoot somebody, not having a gun!". XHR for instance (maybe more clearly than setTimeout) is such a gun. If the "untrusted code" is not really needing XHR, then it is just good sense to take the risk away, by dropping this privilege/functionality.

4) I think (also in the context of the replies) this question has evolved. I think it is clear, yet please post comment if not so. While initially [Juhana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana) said:

> It's *a bit* unclear[...]

I understand that it was not *totally* unclear, and hence now it might have reached enough clarity (please consider the helpful answers) to allow for "deholding"/"freeing the Question". Also if you found the question interesting enough to **hold** it, then now would be the time to find it interesting enough to upvote it ;)

Comment: It's a bit unclear how restricting access to native functions would give more security. Is this server-side or client-side JavaScript?

Comment: thank you. On the server-side (while not wanting to limit it to this) making access to the `fs = require("fs");` or require itself would make it impossible for any subjected code parts to make changes to the filesystem. Since some code is not even needing this it would decrease risk. This code (once loosing the privilege) could not pose a thread to the files, I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to get the original function and blacklisting can't work because you'll miss something e.g.

```
Window.prototype.setTimeout.call(window,'alert(1)');
```

One solution to this problem is to create a whitelisted sandbox. I've created such a sandbox called MentalJS. This sandbox rewrites all your code with a suffix of $ for example alert(1) becomes alert$(1) this allows you to choose which functions/objects are allowed within the sandbox.

The code is available here:
http://code.google.com/p/mentaljs/

and a demo:
http://businessinfo.co.uk/labs/MentalJS/MentalJS.html

Comment: Wow, Great idea! Sure this whitelist is interesting and the way (parsing of code, which is possible in a script language is ingenious!) great! ... Having as it seems more than others dealt with this security aware aspect ... can you think of a good reason why there is no plain `delete window.setTimeout` way of solving the problem?.... Maybe you could even enrich the answer stating who came your interest in this sandboxing.

Comment: Because there are so many ways to get the original code such as the one shown above you are fighting an endless war that you cannot win, one mistake and your blacklist is bypassed. Another easy way to get the original setTimeout is to use an iframe for example. Using ES5 functionality such as defineProperty can make it easier to lock down functions but again this is a blacklist and only one leak is required.

Comment: Thanks for the aclarification. I am convinced of the benefit of whitelist over blacklist in getting towards an relieable least priviledge situation.... What I actually intended to ask, is if you would it enriching if there was an in ES functionality to reliably white/blacklist (hence obsoleting a parsing). I have to start testing you referenced MetalJS for breakout via code-obfuscation. Or has this risk been already dealt with. Parsing is an art

Comment: ES5 offers no way to whitelist and this was a topic I brought up on the ES mailing list. MentalJS has been battle tested by a lot of hackers and the parsing is very strong. The "hack test" button goes through all the previous exploits to make sure they don't happen again and so far the parsing hasn't been broken for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses the [Caja compiler](https://developers.google.com/caja/) in these situations. The unprivileged code is then run either in a server-side sandbox or (in browsers that support ES5) a client-side strict mode sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to this interesting tool. Gotta give it look. You use it?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I only use it in Google Apps Scripts (where Google forces you to use it). But if I ever happen to work on a portal that includes widgets from different sources, I’d certainly consider using it.